# how to add rapidjson header file in c++ program

Tags: c++, error-handling, header-files, dev-c++, rapidjson

Actually i added rapidjson files in my project. But while compiling this program it shows me an error.

Error message

[Error] rapidjson.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

D:\Ramya\Makefile.win  recipe for target 'main_1.o' failed

here main_1 is my file name.

please anyone help me with this. Thanks !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "rapidjson.h"
#include "document.h"

using namespace std;

using namespace rapidjson;

Document document;


void parse_file(void)
{
    
    /* Open the example.json file in read mode */
        FILE* fp = fopen("example.json", "r"); 

        /* Declare read buffer */
        char readBuffer[65536];

        /* Declare stream for reading the example stream */
        FileReadStream is(fp, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));


        /* Parse example.json and store it in `document` */
        document.ParseStream(is);

        /* Close the example.json file*/
        fclose(fp);
    
}



int main()
{
    char name[50];
    int t_value;
    parse_file();
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Have you put `rapidjson.h` in the same folder as `document.h`? If you swap places of the lines  `#include "rapidjson.h"` and `#include "document.h"` does it fail to include `document.h` then?

Comment: I've voting to close this question since you haven't provided enough information.